# browsers send Options instead of Post after changing http header

Tags: http, backbone.js, cross-domain, restlet, cors

```
/*set the response header*/
    Form responseHeaders = (Form) getResponse().getAttributes().get("org.restlet.http.headers"); 
    if (responseHeaders == null) { 
        responseHeaders = new Form(); 
        responseHeaders.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        responseHeaders.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE");
        getResponse().getAttributes().put("org.restlet.http.headers", responseHeaders); 
    }
```

I added this in my restlet 2.0 code to allow for cross domain access, this does make the first GET to work on page load, but when I try to do POST later(with backbone model.save()), browser sends Options with a null entity instead.

It does send the right POST if I did not add the code above

This happens on Opera, Firefox, and Chrome (works fine if I start chrome with --disable-web-security), so i assume it is still a browser security issue, could anyone provide explanations on why this would happen and what might be the fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [What is the HTTP OPTIONS method?](http://zacstewart.com/2012/04/14/http-options-method.html)

> This method allows the client to determine the options and/or requirements associated with a resource, or the capabilities of a server, without implying a resource action or initiating a resource retrieval.

I have fought several times with *CORS* issues and I have always solved them with the method of *try and error* my suggestion for your case is add `OPTIONS` to your *Allow Methods* :

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

And make your server to respond to `OPTIONS` request with an `*`, in Sinatra is like this:

```
options "/*" do
  "*"
end
```

#### Update

For the new issue explained in the comment about the error `header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.`

Try to add another CORS header:

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
```

Comment: after I added Options headler and returing a json representation, Im getting :Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.  I don't really know Sinatra, any suggestions on how do that in Restlet?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for fguillen's advice, have some googling I found the way that would work

```
/*set the response header*/
    Form responseHeaders = (Form) getResponse().getAttributes().get("org.restlet.http.headers"); 
    if (responseHeaders == null) { 
        responseHeaders = new Form(); 
        responseHeaders.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        responseHeaders.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"); 
        responseHeaders.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
        getResponse().getAttributes().put("org.restlet.http.headers", responseHeaders); 
    }
```

so this is the right code to inject for cors in Restlet 2.0
do not miss responseHeaders.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type"); at least when you are dealing with backbone

Answer (score 0):

Slightly off topic but I thought it might be useful for somebody and save time.
I was having **CORS** issues with **uwsgi** server and **backbone**. This is part of my uwsgi.ini file which seem  to work for POSTing.

```
[uwsgi]
add-header = Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
add-header = Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, x-requested-with, content-type                                                                 
add-header = Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,PUT,OPTIONS,DELETE
add-header = Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
add-header = Accept: application/json
```

As mentioned by fguillen server needs to reply '*' for OPTIONS request.

Answer (score 0):

Below code can be used to resolve cross domain issue in Restlet 2.0

```
Form responseHeaders = (Form) getResponse().getAttributes().get("org.restlet.http.headers"); 
if (responseHeaders == null) { 
    responseHeaders = new Form(); 
    getResponse().getAttributes().put("org.restlet.http.headers", responseHeaders); 
} 
responseHeaders.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); 
responseHeaders.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,DELETE,PUT,POST,OPTIONS");
responseHeaders.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type"); 
responseHeaders.add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "false"); 
responseHeaders.add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "60");
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this link could give you some hints about how CORS works and its support in Restlet with the `CorsFilter`:

- **Understanding and using CORS** - https://templth.wordpress.com/2014/11/12/understanding-and-using-cors/

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score 0):

On a different content the code give below works for Restlet 2.1 upwards.

```
import org.restlet.engine.header.Header;



private static final String HEADERS_KEY = "org.restlet.http.headers";



@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

static Series<Header> getMessageHeaders(Message message) {

ConcurrentMap<String, Object> attrs = message.getAttributes();

Series<Header> headers = (Series<Header>) attrs.get(HEADERS_KEY);

if (headers == null) {

         headers = new Series<Header>(Header.class);

     Series<Header> prev = (Series<Header>) 

          attrs.putIfAbsent(HEADERS_KEY, headers);

    if (prev != null) { headers = prev; }

     }

   return headers;
```

}

```
//The JSON Query "GET"
@Get("json")

 public Representation toJson()

  {

   getMessageHeaders(getResponse()).add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); 

   getMessageHeaders(getResponse()).add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,OPTIONS");

   getMessageHeaders(getResponse()).add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with,Content-Type"); 

   getMessageHeaders(getResponse()).add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true"); 

   getMessageHeaders(getResponse()).add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "60"); 

  return get();
}
```